# Switch on Child List

Tags: c#, inheritance

I understand the part that it is possible to switch om a parent type through inheritance.

```
//This works fine

        public class Child1: Parent 
        {
           //props
        }

        public class Child2: Parent 
        {
           //props
        }

        public async Task<Parent> SaveItem(Parent item)
        {
            switch (item)
            {
                case Child1 child1:
                    DoActionforchild1
                break;
                case Child2 child2:
                    DoActionforchild2
                break;
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
```

But i can not get it to work with a list or IList

```
//Does not work

        public class Child1: Parent 
        {
           //props
        }

        public class Child2: Parent 
        {
           //props
        }

        public async Task<IList<Parent>> SaveItems(IList<Parent> items)
        {
            switch (items)
            {
                case IList<Child1> childs1:
                    DoActionforchilds1
                break;
                case IList<Child2> child2:
                    DoActionforchild2
                break;
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
```

Can someone please explain why this does not work and what the correct way is to switch on a type of Child List

Comment: A list of `IList<Child>` ***does not inherit*** from `IList<Parent>`. They are two different types.

Comment: Imagine you had a `IList<Parent>` - it could contain both `Child1` items and `Child2` items. What you you expect the compiler to do when you try to case it as `IList<Child1>`?

Comment: Likewise imagine that you had a `IList<Child1>` that you could case to `IList<Parent>` - you could then add `Child2` to the original `IList<Child1>` - BOOM!

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone please explain why this does not work

Because `IList<T>` is invariant with respect to `T`, so a `IList<Child1>` cannot be used in place of a `IList<Parent>`.

> what the correct way is to switch on a type of Child List

One way would be to use `IEnumerable<Parent>` as the argument type:

```
public async Task<IList<Parent>> SaveItems(IEnumerable<Parent> items)
```

For `IEnumerable<out T>`, `T` is *covariant*, so a `List<Child1>` or `List<Child2>` can be passed.

More information on [generic variance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance).

Comment: Woah! What does "invariant" mean? And "covariant"? (Please don't rely on links.)

Comment: And I would suggest that covariance doesn't apply here anyway.

Comment: @Enigmativity There are _many_ answers on SO that explain the terminology. I'm not going to repeat those definitions here; I've merely highlighted why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Enigmativity "_I would suggest that covariance doesn't apply here anyway_" Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Sorry just tested you solution using IEnumerable. Did not work. i think it is not possible like @Enigmativity suggested.

Comment: @user3497156 What exactly isn't working? Here is an example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/QWDXNt

Comment: thats odd. In my original project it does not switch to the child1 but gos to the default option. But you are right your example works. Is it possible this is a new feature? i am still using .net Core 3.1?

Comment: No, this should work in .Net Core 3.1 too. Can you give more information as to what is happening for you?

Comment: I think there must be a problem somewhere else. We are transferringdata over grpc stream to a microservice. there de reconstruct the list of childs. ( var childlist= new List<Parent>() ). Then we add all thechild items to the list by childlist.add((Parent) child1);.

Comment: Ah, so you construct a `List<Parent>` that contains entirely `Child1` or `Child2` items, not a `List<Child1>` or `List<Child2>`?

Comment: Yes. the list<Parent> had always only 1 type of childs. never mixed. Thank you four your help. i will look in to it soms more. Have a nice day

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay - Contravariance is in play here, not covariance. You can't cast the OP's collections to a more derived type. You can only cast to a more general type.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you can't do it is that `IList<Child>` doesn't inherit from `IList<Parent>`.

In the case of lists should iterate (with a for loop) over the parent list and do the assignment as you do in a one-to-one.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to check whether all items of your list are either of `Child1` or of `Child2`. You can use [`All`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=net-5.0) to do so:

```
public async Task<IList<Parent>> SaveItems(IList<Parent> items)
        {
            if(items.All(x => x is Child1)
            {
                DoActionforchilds1();
            }
            else if(items.All(x => x is Child2)
            {
                DoActionforchild2();
            }
            else
            {
                // mixed list containing Child1 and Child2
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Am I right that you're advocating not saving anything should any one element not be of the same type as the others?

Comment: I don't know OP's use case. But he wanted to cast `IList<Parent>` to `IList<Child1>`, which only makes sense if the list contains only items of type `Child1`.

Comment: Just because the OP had the wrong impression about casting, it shouldn't mean that his solution shouldn't be robust.

Answer (score 1):

A list of `IList<Child>` does not inherit from `IList<Parent>`. They are two different types.

Imagine you had a `IList<Parent>` - it could contain both `Child1` items and `Child2` items. What you you expect the compiler to do when you try to case it as `IList<Child1>`?

Likewise imagine that you had a `IList<Child1>` that you could case to `IList<Parent>` (which you can't) - you could then add `Child2` to the original `IList<Child1>` - BOOM!

The easy thing is to call `SaveItem` on each item in the list without trying to cast it to anything. Let `SaveItem` do the work.

With the addition of some extension methods to bridge between enumerables and tasks then you could do this:

```
public Task<IList<Parent>> SaveItems(IList<Parent> items) =>
    from results in 
        from parent in items
        from result in SaveItem(parent)
        select result
    select new List<Parent>(results) as IList<Parent>;
```

These are the extension methods to make it work:

```
public static class EnumerableTaskEx
{
    public static async Task<R> Select<T, R>(this Task<T> task, Func<T, R> s) =>
        s(await task);

    public static Task<IEnumerable<R>> SelectMany<T, R>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, Task<R>> k) =>
        from t in source
        from r in k(t)
        select r;

    public static Task<IEnumerable<R>> SelectMany<T, U, R>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, Task<U>> k, Func<T, U, R> s) =>
        from t in source
        from u in k(t)
        select s(t, u);
}
```